# How can I implement a reflexive primary/foreign key relationship in Access?

Tags: ms-access-2010

MS Office 265 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016
I'm a novice with this.

I have a table called pedigree.  I has 3 columns...

Name (text)
ID (auto increment integer, primary key)
Parent_ID (integer)

I want to implement a constraint which will require that the "parent_ID" value of each record exists as the ID value of some other record i the same table (a reflexive primary/foreign key setup).

In Access, I went to the "Database Tool" tab, then "Relationships", then opened the table up twice and tied that ID column of one to the "Parent_ID" of the other.  It didn't complain, saved out OK.  When I run it, it doesn't seem to work.  I can put records in the table with Parent_ID values outside of the available ID value pool.

Any clues?

Also, if there's a different/better way to do this, I'm all ears.  I read about the "Database Tools" -> "Relationships" approach on the web somewhere but am open to anything that might work.

Comment: Did you mark the checkbox: _Enforce Referential Integrity_?

Comment: After struggling with this a bit, I was able to set the "Enforce Referrential Integrity" and it works now.  Thanks Gustav !

Answer (score 1):

And the solution for me (the novice) was...

Set the "Enforce Referrential Integrity" of the relationship.

Thanks Gustav for the hint !